# How is the right python class chosen

Tags: python, inheritance

I thought I knew Python.  Guess not really.
I do `pip install pyopengltk` on Windows and linux.  The demo program creates and uses a class

`class AppOgl(OpenGLFrame):`

The inherited class **OpenGLFrame** is defined in both win32.py and linux.py in the pyopengltk package. Sort of like the class diamond problem, but it is the exact same named **OpenGLFrame** class.  No multiple inheritance.  How is the right version from win32.py or linux.py chosen?  I see both files on both platforms are compiled in the site-package's `__pycache__` after use.

Comment: https://github.com/jonwright/pyopengltk/blob/master/pyopengltk/__init__.py#L23

Comment: If you only import one of `win32.py` or `linux.py` (which seems likely), you get the module defined in the imported module. If you import both, the second module overrides the class defined by the first.

Comment: (And as jordanm's comment points out, only one *is*, in fact, imported.)

Comment: jordanm - Oh, gosh.  I ran across __init__.py being used in packages but inconviently forgot that.  Thanks very much.  I can sleep at nights again.